# Hibernate @SoftDelete problem with @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement soft delete feature using hibernate (6.4.1.Final) `@SoftDelete` annotation and I am encountering problem with `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` on the given referenced soft-deletable entity.

Stating:

```
To-one attribute (com.example.EntityA.referencedEntityB) cannot be mapped as LAZY as its associated entity is defined with @SoftDelete
```

My question is: *Why is it not possible to have the referenced entity to be lazy loaded if it is soft-deletable?*

I tried to search the answer in [hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17164), but with no success.

Comment: Can you add `@NotFound ( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )` to mapping ? And tell me if it fix the problem and you get `null` instead of this message.

Comment: It does fix the problem. Even with `@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION )`. But why?

Comment: I guess that the problem is in `FetchType.LAZY` it return a proxy of object and that object could be soft deleted and this is the reason of the error yo get . Before this annotation it was throwing `EntityNotFoundException` if the pointed  entity  in `@ManyToOne` was deleted. If you change it to `FetchType.EAGER` it should work because entity is fetched on the initialization and no proxy is invoked

Comment: Yes, now I see it. But it basically do the same as if I set the FetchType.EAGER and I want to avoid that as much as I can.

Comment: You could see something related to your question here [soft-delete-annotation-example](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/soft-delete-annotation-example/)

Comment: Unfortunately there are 0 mentions of @ManyToOne mappings. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Hibernate 6.4.4 outputs the following log when using the `@NotFound` annotation: `...uses both @NotFound and FetchType.LAZY. @ManyToOne and @OneToOne associations mapped with @NotFound are forced to EAGER fetching.`